# IEDriver implementation fails the test

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Webdriver(without IEDriver implementation) 2.23 API on windows7 machine with JDK7 and JRE7. The test scripts are working fine as expected but when i introduced IEDriver the script fails in a page with cannot click on element error message as that corresponding element is not visible. i have double checked with my application for the locator. The same can be clicked with out IEDriver implementation. I have tried by simulating all the click types including context click by Action class. No use. All click types returns the same result. Any help ?

Comment: even upgrading to latest version needs IEDriver implementation. Actaully i am trying to that. 

     driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click(); is the troubling point in my code

Comment: Try using SendKeys(Keys.ENTER), instead of click() method.

Comment: @Sri, I tried all of them, The problem is the Element itself not visible.This is peculiar. Because the same is working fine without IEDriver. Also, IEDriver implementation does not affects all other operation. Only this particular Element is accessible.

Comment: @Karthikeyan What do you mean when you say that the element is not visible? Do you mean that the driver can't find the element? Or the element is not displayed? Could you post the exception or error that you get?

Comment: @user1177636 No the element is in the middle of the page.

Comment: @Sergio The element is displayed but it is not able to clicked by the webdriver. i have done a work around finally. THe same has posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i was manage to click the above said Element with the help of following code.

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.name("Complete"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we); // common for all we
```

The real source is [here](http://dgselissuefix.blogspot.in/2013/04/selenium-webdriver-element-is-not.html). This may helpful for someone.

Comment: It's good that it works, but the code is not very clean. In my case IEDriver has no problems to click on WebElement objects. I have some ideas of what may be happening and probably we can get a better solution for it. Could you tell me what happens if you run `we.click()` directly.

Comment: @ Sergio Pelin i do agree. This is peculiar for me too. Because i can able to perform the same(CLick) actions with other elements. This is happening only with this element. i am unable to upload my stack trace here. The Exact error is: Cannot click on the element as it is not visible.

Comment: @ Karthikeyan Ok.Two more questions before acting. 1: Do you have some emerging element around, e.g. saying "Loading..." or similar? 2: Could you insert in your code, before `we.click()`, a line to print out the following value `we.isDisplayed()`? Tell me if it is `true` or `false` and next we are going to workaround it.

Comment: @Sergio Pelin. we.isDisplayed()? is yields false

Comment: @ Karthikeyan Ok. I'll post a possible solution. Let me know if something is wrong or it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that the element is actually visible and the error's log says it is not, I think that the problem might be due to Internet Explorer's slowness. You could use this method for a quick test:

```
boolean isElementDisplayed(final WebDriver driver, final WebElement element, final int timeoutInSeconds) {
    try {
        ExpectedCondition condition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(final WebDriver webDriver) {
                return element.isDisplayed();
            }
        };

        Wait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
        w.until(condition);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //if you get here, it's because the element is not displayed after timeoutInSeconds
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.name("Complete"));

if (isElementDisplayed(driver, we, 30)) {
    we.click();
}
```

This will make the driver wait (30 sec max.) till the element **we** becomes visible and then the driver clicks on it. 
If it works, then my supposition is right and you could change the method for:

```
 void clickOn(final WebDriver driver, final WebElement element, final int timeoutInSeconds) {
    try {
        ExpectedCondition condition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(final WebDriver webDriver) {
                element.click();
                return true;
            }
        };

        Wait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
        w.until(condition);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //probably some kind of exception thrown here
    }
    return;
}
```

and use it instead of `we.click()`, like:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.name("Complete"));
clickOn(driver, we, 30);
```

The code above is an approximation to let you check your issue in a quick and clear way and, if you end up using it, you should adapt it to *your* structure of code. This kind of utility code should never appear in your tests. Your test code should be clean and the same for all the environments (browsers, version, SOs, etc.). Keep the workarounds separately, e.g. some kind of `util` package.

Also, the method's signature is 'overweight'. Restructuring your util code, you should be able to write in your tests just this: `clickOn(element)`.

Hope it helps ;)

**UPDATE** Actually, with these components I had never run into a similar problem:

1. `selenium-server-standalone` version 2.32.0
2. IEDriverServer_x64_2.30.1.exe

Comment: Oops, 'isElementDisplayed(driver, we, 30)' is always false here.
But 
    'System.out.println("The Size of the button is"+driver.findElements(By.name("Complete")).size());' is 1.

Comment: @ Karthikeyan Ok. Resuming what we have here: 1-The code works with other browsers (at least with FF); 2-With IE Selenium is able to find the button, but finds it like not displayed (i.e. not clickable); 3-The issue is not due to IE slowness, as the button stays not displayed even after 30 seconds. Could you do the following: 1-Change the name of the button for something less common (e.g. 'MySeleniumButton'), to just be sure that Selenium finds this and not other element; 2-Open your application in IE, verify that you are able to click the button and then copy and post here button's HTML code.

Comment: 1.No its not working with FF too.

2.Yes, it can find it. Hence System.out.println("The Size of the button is"+driver.findElements(By.name("Complete")).size());' is 1.

I have no access to the AUT code for now. The same is working with selenium 2.23(With out IEDriver)

Comment: Well, what we know is that something with the name "Complete" is found; from the trace we cannot be sure it is the issue button. If you are absolutely sure there is no other element that has this name and that the button element definitely has the attribute **name = "Complete"**, then it's ok. You don't need the AUT code to see the HTML. Just start the application that you are testing in IE, press F12 and find the code for the button. Copy the code contained inside the HTML element whose attribute **name = "Complete"**

Comment: Also, perhaps, we should have started from the other side: the test environment configuration :) I'll add to the answer the configuration that works for me without problems. Have a look at that, too, and before going on, update it if necessary and check again if the issue is solved.

Comment: Great, i am sure that no other element is with the given xpath. i have also noticed that two more buttons are facing the same issue which are in the same div of complete Button.So i suspect the div may causes the visibility issue. as per my observation they also sounds good. no complex structure.

Comment: What you say about div is possible; that's why I wanted to check the HTML. Anyway, try to avoid searching for elements by xpath, it's better to find them by class, name, id, etc. Also, remember to update your Selenium components, as it might solve your issue alltogether.

Comment: i suspect the div because all other buttons inside that div cause the same problem. I have verified the HTML right then after your suggestion. The div too has nothing special. Just a div containing some table stuffs. inside td the buttons are placed. i have tried with other possible locating technique other than xpath too. the issue still exists.